# Scale chart Y axis labels

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a vb.net windows form chart control on a form that displays a line chart of data that is made available in *milli*-gravities.

e.g. `5` gravities is given as `5000` milli-gravities, meaning that the Y-axis label is `5000`

Is it possible to plot the same data but, have the Y-axis use labels in gravities, instead of milli-gravities? That is, for a Y data point of `5000`, the Y axis label should be `5`, or in other words have `label value = auto label value / 1000`

The data is currently bound to the chart using the following syntax

```
Chart1.Series.Add("Z Axis") 'Add multiple series
Chart1.Series.Add("Z RMS")

For Each Series In Chart1.Series 'Set each series to line type
    Series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
Next

Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 100000 'Start the Y axis limits at 100 gravities
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 100000 'The max & min are changeable by user input
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()

Chart1.Series("Z Axis").Points.DataBindY(record.Samples, "Z") 'Add the Y data points
Chart1.Series("Z RMS").Points.DataBindY(record.Samples, "RmsZ")
```

I thought maybe setting the `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format` might help, but I'm not sure how to use a format string to *shorten* an integer?